# Swift Custom UITableViewCell with programmatically created UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to use a custom TableViewCell Class in my programmatically created UITableView and i can't figure out why this don't get to work. I've used custom TableViewCell Classes a few times without any problems (set the Classname in Storyboard) but here i have no Storyboard to set the Class which should be used to generate the Cells.

I'm doing this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    self.popupTableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCellPopup.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "popupTableViewCell")
    ...
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("popupTableViewCell") as CustomTableViewCellPopup
    ...
    return cell
}

class CustomTableViewCellPopup: UITableViewCell {

    var message: UILabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        println("I'm running!")
        self.message.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10);
        self.message.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        self.addSubview(self.message)
    }

}
```

The println() Output never appears. The TableView gets rendered without the additional UILabel (message). Just like an out of the box UITableViewCell.

The same way (without registerClass()) i'm running a TableView with custom Cells from the Storyboard (the Classname directly defined in the Storyboard Inspector) without any problems.

Have you an idea why the custom Class don't get used?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` won't get called unless the cell is loaded from a xib or storyboard. Move your custom code from `awakeFromNib` into `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` because that's the initializer used by the tableView when you call its `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method

Answer (score 3):

You're not seeing the println output because that's in `awakeFromNib`, which is only called if you cell comes from a storyboard or XIB. Here you're just registering the class with the table, so there's no Nib loading going on. Try making a call to configure the cell from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, rather than configuring in awakeFromNib.

`initWithCoder:` won't be called for the same reason - try overriding `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`.